# C# BasicAuthentication implementation approach

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication, bearer-token

I am thinking of creating a web api application using .Net. Here is what I am thinking of how to implement this.

```
The application will be serving clients who's credentials I will create separately. 
These credentials will be encrypted using my own private key. 
I will provide them this encrypted text. 
They will use this encrypted text in the Authorization header.
On the server I will implement an AuthorizationFilterAttribute. 
In here I will decrypt and validate the user. 
And allow it to go to the resource.
```

I honestly do not understand this topic in depth. Therefore I was wondering if my approach will work.
In my tests I have seen that all requests do hit the AuthorizationFilterAttribute which means I will have the chance to check credentials on every request.
Bearer Token might not work as for that I will need (my understanding) at least 2 requests one to get token and next one to get actual resource. Please guide.
Thanks

Comment: There isn't enough information here to solve a problem. No mention of who creates the credentials, what the private key is. You mention [Basic Authorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) but are talking about Bearer tokens, which are two separate authorization/authentication patterns.

Comment: I think you missed the question. Here is the text in question where I state who will create credentials with which private key "These credentials will be encrypted using my own private key. 
I will provide them this encrypted text." I spoke about Basic all through my question, only in the last 3 lines I mentioned Bearer token. I appreciate your response..Please guide..thanks